# imagemagick equivelent in python

Tags: python, image, photoshop

```
import os
cmd='convert -fill blue -size 300x100  -pointsize 60  -gravity center \
          label:"Hello World"     label_gravity.psd'
os.system(cmd)
```

What are ways of creating a psd file on windows, I found this method but it only runs on Linux distro (imagemagick), is there a python library (that can save .psd) or a simple way of running this on windows?

Comment: Both python and imagemagick are available on windows. Have you tried installing and testing them first? http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows

Comment: @Ludo21South how can I run it though it doesn't work in cmd as above

Comment: I don't since I don't run python on windows. The following link however mentions installing and testing Imagemagick:http://web.mit.edu/GRAPHICs/share/ImageMagick/www/windows.html ..... a quote from this page: "Testing The Installation
Select “Command Prompt” from the Windows Start menu. Within the window type" which leads me to believe that it should be possible to run your command in windows as well.

Comment: @Ludo21South is there a way to create a psd file on windows (python) ?

Comment: Like I mentioned before; I don't run python on windows, nor do I use imagemagick, so I think I won't be able to answer that for you. Maybe some other user knows or you could use your google-fu for it?

Comment: Not sure why you think **ImageMagick** doesn't run on Windows. It does. Install it and try this in a **Command Prompt** `magick -size 64x100 xc:blue sample.psd`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Python subprocess.

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'fullpath_to/convert -fill blue -size 300x100  -pointsize 60  -gravity center label:"Hello World" label_gravity.psd'

subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Provide your full path to convert.